# Fail on creating a trigger SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'grade' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `id_customer` INT ZEROFILL NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY ,
  `fname` varchar(45) not NULL,
  `lname` varchar(45) not NULL,
  `bday` date not NULL,
  `country` char(15) not NULL,  
  `address` varchar(50) not NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(10) not null
 );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory` (
  `id_product` INT zerofill NOT NULL auto_increment   PRIMARY KEY,
  `model` varchar(45) not null,
  `price_new` FLOAT not null,
  `grade` char(10) not null,
  `launch_year` year not null,
  `final_price` FLOAT(8),
  `stock` INT(5) not null
 );

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check after insert ON inventory
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           IF inventory.grade = 'bad' THEN
               update NEW.final_price = 2;
           elseif inventory.grade = 'good' then
                update new.final_price = 0;
           END IF;
       END;//
delimiter ;
```

I want to create a trigger that after i insert on a table inventory if the quality is one thing he does something if it is other thing it puts some other value.
But i get the error SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'grade' in 'field list'.
Why?

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake.

Comment: A trigger can't update the same table it's triggering on.

Comment: Ohh soo i need another table in the midle to find a way. Ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to modify values in the new row being inserted, use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE insert ON inventory
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           IF NEW.grade = 'bad' THEN
              SET NEW.final_price = 2;
           elseif NEW.grade = 'good' then
                SET NEW.final_price = 0;
           END IF;
       END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: It gave me an error SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: Check your typing. Works for me https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mNXSGiWQozGvHBz8aRdFe7/0#&togetherjs=eBKVFcNF8D

Comment: I used the same as you, i created a new database. SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5